# XSLT pass param as XML document to stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, wso2-esb

I was wondering if it is possible to pass a parameter to a XSLT mediator/spreadsheet as a XML node, instead of string. Passing it as string makes it impossible for me to navigate through the nodes with XPath. I am using XSLT mediator in Wso2 Integration Studio. I have tried already to save the parameter different ways, `<property expression="$body/*" name="parameter" scope="default" type="STRING"/>` and `<property expression="$body/*" name="parameter" scope="default" type="OM"/>` did not work out. I have tried to parse it with `saxon:parse()` but it did not work as well. I also noticed that `<` was replaced by `&lt;` inside the spreadsheet parameter, so I decided to replace it by using `<xsl:variable name="parameterXml" select="replace($parameter, '&lt;', '<')"/>` but I did not suceed. I know that I can just merge payloads I am interested in, creating potentially enormous document, then use xslt to get the data I need, but I would like to avoid that solution.

The question I believe concerns xslt in general, but so far I could not find the answer or find a workaround myself.

The spreadsheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="XsltTransformer" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:param name="firstParameter"/>
            <xsl:param name="secondParameter"/>
            <xsl:param name="someValue"/>
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <someWrapper>
                   <xsl:call-template name="firstTemplate">
                       <xsl:with-param name="firstParameter" select="$firstTemplate/*[name()='someChilds']"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                   <xsl:call-template name="secondTemplate">
                       <xsl:with-param name="firstParameter" select="$firstTemplate/*[name()='someChilds']"/>
                       <xsl:with-param name="secondParameter" select="$secondParameter"/>
                       <xsl:with-param name="someValue" select="$someValue"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                </someWrapper>
            </xsl:template>
            <!-- Other templates -->
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```

`firstParameter` and `secondParameter` are xml nodes. `someValue` is just plain string.

**Edit:**
The processor is: **Saxonica** version **2.0**

Comment: Why is the question tagged as XSLT 1.0 but then mentions `saxon:parse` or even `replace` (XPath 2 or later function)? As for XSLT in general, sure, you can pass in nodes, but how you do that depends on the processor's API and on its tree model and tree/document builder.

Comment: The answer in general is yes, you can pass in a document node as the value of the stylesheet parameter. However, whether this is feasible in practice depends on which processor you are using and how you are invoking the transformation. I've no idea whether "Wso2 integration studio" allows you to do this.

Comment: Seems like I intruduced ambiguity about the version. After checking it with `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>` it turns out it is actually a **Saxonica** version **2.0** @MartinHonnen . Is there any special way/tag I should mark stylesheet paramters with to make it pass actual nodes instead of strings. How do I parse those strings in order to make them tree model, can you point some valuable sources explaining that? Thank for your replies.

Comment: Can you check `system-property('xsl:product-name')` and `system-property('xsl:product-version')` as well? But in general I guess you have to wait until someone knowledgeable about parameter passing with your platform comes up with the right way. Saxon via its API would allow you to set the parameter as an `XdmNode` in s9api or a `Source` (I think) with JAXP but how your platform passes XML documents on to XSLT I don't know.

Comment: After reading both properties I got the following results @MartinHonnen . The `product-name` holds value of **SAXON**, and `product-version` is **HE 9.4.0.4**.

Comment: This means it is a pure XSLT 2 processor with no built-in support for XPath 3 or 3.1's `parse-xml` nor Saxon EE or PE's extension functions to parse xml. Otherwise, as I have said before, it all depends on how the environment uses Saxon's API and the parameter it passes in. Unfortunately I have no idea how wso2esb does that and which options it offers.

Comment: When you say "firstParameter and secondParameter are xml nodes. someValue is just plain string.", is that part of a type you assign to the parameter value? Or you just setting a value of e.g. `foo` in the last case and of e.g. `<root><foo>bar</foo></root>` in the first two cases?

Comment: I mean both. `firstParameter` and `secondParameter` are of wso2 type OM, which is I believe for XML nodes, also they are of `<root><foo>bar</foo></root>` structure. `someValue` is just database string variable saved to property of type `STRING` and passed to xslt mediator.